# binding to an Observable Collection in a usercontrol and getting notifications from it

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, observablecollection

I've been looking through some other questions here that look similar to my issue, but none have the answer. So, here goes...

I'm developing a C# application using WPF and the MVVM pattern. I have a UserControl (called GroupTree) that contains a dependency property:

```
  public static DependencyProperty ChartGroupsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ChartGroups", typeof(ChartGroupCollection), typeof(GroupTree),
                                                      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata() { DefaultValue=new ChartGroupCollection(),  PropertyChangedCallback = OnChartGroupsChanged, BindsTwoWayByDefault = true });
    public ChartGroupCollection ChartGroups
    {
        get { return (ChartGroupCollection)GetValue(ChartGroupsProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ChartGroupsProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private static void OnChartGroupsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OldValue != e.NewValue)
        {
            // Nothing at the moment
        }
    }
```

Its of type ChartGroupCollection which is defined so:

```
public class ChartGroupCollection : ObservableCollection<ChartGroup>
{
}
```

The ChartGroup contains properties that use INotifyProperty and I've independently verified that all the change events that should fire for the main collection do so properly.

The MainWindow.Xaml that uses the control:

```
   <Controls:GroupTree x:Name="Groups" ChartGroups="{Binding MainGroups}" />
```

I have another control that binds to the ChartGroups Value in the GroupTree Control:

```
   <Controls:ChartsControl x:Name="Charts1_1" Tree="{Binding ElementName=Groups, Path=ChartGroups}" />
```

What I want to happen is when the GroupTree ChartGroups Value changes, for this to notify the ChartsControl dynamically of those changes and update accordingly. But at the moment, no joy. The data is there, because if force a refresh of the ChartsControl manually the changes show. I've tried binding to the MainGroups property hoping that would work, but that doesn't either.

I've probably missed something blindingly obvious, but I'm not sure what. Any ideas?

Rob

Answer (score 4):

ObservableCollection only listens to the changes occur in the collection like items being added or removed and it does not notify about any changes happened in the individual items of its collection.

The following class enhances the funtionality of ObservableCollection by registering itself to the INofityPropertyChanged event of the items being added and raises the CollectionChanged event of the ObservableCollection when a property of an item of the collection changes.

Calling the ClearItems at the end releases all event handlers.

More details can be found from the below link.

[How to Listen to Property Changes of Items of an ObservableCollection](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/694370/How-to-Listen-to-Property-Chang)

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Collections;

namespace VJCollections
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     This class adds the ability to refresh the list when any property of
    ///     the objects changes in the list which implements the INotifyPropertyChanged. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">
    public class ItemsChangeObservableCollection<T> :
           ObservableCollection<T> where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            {
                RegisterPropertyChanged(e.NewItems);
            }
            else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
            {
                UnRegisterPropertyChanged(e.OldItems);
            }
            else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
            {
                UnRegisterPropertyChanged(e.OldItems);
                RegisterPropertyChanged(e.NewItems);
            }

            base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
        }

        protected override void ClearItems()
        {
            UnRegisterPropertyChanged(this);
            base.ClearItems();
        }

        private void RegisterPropertyChanged(IList items)
        {
            foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in items)
            {
                if (item != null)
                {
                    item.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
                }
            }
        }

        private void UnRegisterPropertyChanged(IList items)
        {
            foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in items)
            {
                if (item != null)
                {
                    item.PropertyChanged -= new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
                }
            }
        }

        private void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @gunr2171 - Edited as per your suggestion.

Comment: This is a very useful class that I'm probably going to use going forward, but unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. Even with any change being notified properly, binding the collection through the user control does not result in dynamic updates happening. This is why I'm wondering what is causing the problem.

Comment: @RobMarsh - I am getting the required functionality for free without bothering the above things using ItemsControl, ListBox, TreeView. I wonder what control you are using to bind the ObservableCollection.

Comment: I'm actually binding to another usercontrol, so this is probably the issue... I'll have to have a go with a standard control and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the `PropertyChanged` callback  is only invoked when `PropertyChanged` is raised against the bound property (thus causing the binding to evalutate).

You need the `CollectionChanged` event provided by `INotifyCollectionChanged`. So you have two options:

1. Register for that event in `OnChartGroupsChanged` and handle it yourself (make sure to de-register for the old one, so you don't leak the handle!)
2. Derive from something like `ItemsControl` and use its `Items` property. This removes your dependency property and allows `ItemsControl` to handle all the collection changed stuff for you.

If its feasable, I would go with the second one. If not, utilizing the `CollectionChanged` event shouldn't be *too* bad.